# How to give AUTOINCREMENT to column for particular table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, auto-increment

I have a table called `EMPLOYEE_DETAILS` with these columns:

```
    @EMPLOYEEE_ID,
    @EMPLOYEE_FIRSTNAME,
    @EMPLOYEE_MIDDEL_NAME,
    @EMPLOYEE_LAST_NAME,
    @EMPLOYEE_CODE,
    @EMPLOYEE_WORKDEPT,
    @EMPLOYEE_PHONENO,
    @EMPLOYEEE_HIREDATE,
    @EMPLOYEE_JOB,
    @EMPLOYEE_POSITION,
    @EMPLOYEE_SEX,
    @EMPLOYEE_BIRTHDATE,
    @EMPLOYEE_SALARY,
    @EMPLOYEE_BONUS,
    @EMPLOYEE_COMM
```

Now, `EMPLOYEE_ID` is the primary key, but it does not have autoincrement value.

How to provide autoincrement value if the column has already created without deleting the column structure?

Below is the query that I have tried, but I got an error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IDENTITY'.

Code:

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE_DETAILS 
  ALTER COLUMN EMPLOYEE_ID IDENTITY(1,1);
```

Comment: And the error was?????

Comment: Please see the questions i updated it.

Comment: Then the issue that i would face is the migrating the existing data if, i will delete the tabel structure. how could i resolve that issue then.

Comment: You didn't put the data type.  It should be ALTER COLUMN Employee_ID int IDENTITY(1,1).

Answer (score -2):

To modify the an already created column as autoincrement. Try this query:

```
 ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY EMPLOYEE_ID datatype(length) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

You cannot make an already existing column as an IDENTITY column. Either you drop and recreate the table with the column marked as IDENTITY', or drop the column and add a new IDENTITY` column.

Comment: Then the issue that i would face is the migrating the existing data if, i will delete the tabel structure. how could i resolve that issue then.

Comment: I don't get you. Why would you need to delete the table structure if you modify a property of the existing column

Comment: You cant add identity property to an existing table. You must drop the table and re-create it.